# jasper report studio can't deal with hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I using hibernate framework in my project, i choose to use annotation approches.I'm also using H2 embbeded database "FILE MODE".
Every thing work fine in my editor and in distribuatable jar file.I choose jasper reports to create reports but i hit a problem to setup hibernate datasource in JRSudio.

> Please notce that i have setup the class path to classes folder in JRStudio.

[image]

and her is the stack trace for this problem.

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.hibernate.HibernateDataAdapterService.contributeParameters(HibernateDataAdapterService.java:129)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.AbstractDataAdapterService.test(AbstractDataAdapterService.java:105)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.data.wizard.AbstractDataAdapterWizard$3.runOperations(AbstractDataAdapterWizard.java:162)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.utils.jobs.CheckedRunnableWithProgress$1.run(CheckedRunnableWithProgress.java:59)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.hibernate.HibernateDataAdapterService.contributeParameters(HibernateDataAdapterService.java:102)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty, at table: TTransaction, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(amount)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:276)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:458)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:215)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1149)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1334)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:859)
    ... 9 more
```

Hibernate configuration file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:file:./db/entrepriseLimited;IFEXISTS=TRUE</property>

        <property name="connection.username">myUserName</property>
        <property name="connection.password">myPass</property>


        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <mapping class="bean.Entreprise"/>
        <mapping class="bean.Account"/>
        <mapping class="bean.typeOfTransaction.TypeOfTransaction"/>
        <mapping class="bean.typeOfTransaction.CreditTypeOfTransaction"/>
        <mapping class="bean.typeOfTransaction.DebitTypeOfTransaction"/>
        <mapping class="bean.DebitTaxe"/>
        <mapping class="bean.transaction.Transaction"/>
        <mapping class="bean.transaction.Debit"/>
        <mapping class="bean.transaction.Credit"/>
        <mapping class="bean.person.User"/>
        <mapping class="bean.person.Customer"/>
        <mapping class="bean.person.PhysicPerson"/>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

So what could make this problem ?